# setting intervals with CSS3 animations

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to create a sort of slideshow with CSS. I set several background images which gradually fade in one after another.
What I cannot do, though, is setting an interval of some seconds between an image and the other one, so they do not start fading as soon they are fully rendered.
I do not want to include JQuery otherwise the project would be already complicated since I am already using React. Any ideas?

CSS

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-size: initial;
  animation: animatedBird 60s  infinite;
}

  @keyframes animatedBird {
    0% { background-image: url('../images/arch1.jpg');}    
    25% { background-image: url('../images/computer.jpg');}
    50% { background-image: url('../images/arch2.jpg');}
    75% { background-image: url('../images/computer.jpg');}
    100% { background-image: url('../images/arch1.jpg');} 
  }
```

Comment: Specify _two_ steps for each image … If you specify the same image for 25% _and_ 30% with nothing else in between, then you get that image shown during that time without any fading.

Comment: thanks! it works now!!! Just out of curiosity: what if I had many images, like 20 or so, would you still use % to split their visualization and set a higher time for animation to complete, like 200 seconds?

Comment: For up to that amount of images you should still be good, if it gets into much larger numbers, I would perhaps still use a “classic” JS slideshow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to initially load all the images using multiple background so that you won't have any delay on the animation:

```css
body {
  background-image: 
  url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1040'), /*put the first one on the Top*/
  url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1069'), 
  url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1042');
  background-size:cover;
  animation: animatedBird 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBird {
  0% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1040');
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1069');
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1042');
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1069');
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1040');
  }
}
```

Here is without intial load to see the difference:

```css
body {
  background-size:cover;
  animation: animatedBird 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBird {
  0% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1041');
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1068');
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1043');
  }
  75% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1068');
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1041');
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

And to keep the image for a period of time you can try this:

```css
body {
  background-image: 
  url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1040'), /*put the first one on the Top*/
  url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1069'), 
  url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1042');
  background-size:cover;
  animation: animatedBird 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBird {
  0%,20% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1040');
  }
  25%,45% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1069');
  }
  50%,70% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1042');
  }
  75%,95% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1069');
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1040');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! indeed it helps, but it did not solve my problem...  I want to "freeze" each of those images for a while so they do not start fading in as soon as they are fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
body {
  animation: animatedBird 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes animatedBird {
  0%, 25% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1082');
  }
  50%, 75% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1083');
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1082');
  }
}
```